# how can I align matrices side by side and adjust width with the sheet?

Tags: align, matrices

I have these matrices and I want to align them side by side, two matrices in the first row and the other two in the second row (see an example in the picture). I also want to put the name of the matrix above it. This is my code:

```
 \begin{equation*}
    \begin{matrix}
    1&  -0.325& -0.267& -0.186& -0.249& -0.595& -0.555&\\
    &1& 0.0903& 0.063&  0.084&  0.684&  0.781&\\
    && 1&   0.68&   0.925&  0.295&  0.366&\\
    &&& 1&  0.541&  0.192&  0.213&\\
    &&&&    1&  0.296&  0.361&\\
    &&&&&   1&  0.948&\\
        &&&&&&  1
    \end{matrix}
    %
    \begin{matrix}
    1& -0.264&  -0.153& -0.098& -0.140& -0.496& -0.449
    \\ &1&  0.042&  0.027&  0.039&  0.739&  0.798&
    \\&& 1& 0.627&  0.910&  0.205&  0.336&
    \\&&& 1&    0.450& 0.114&   0.192&
    \\&&&& 1&   0.211&  0.327&
    \\&&&&& 1&  0.949& 
    \\  &&&&&&  1
    \end{matrix}%
    %
    \begin{matrix}
    1&  -0.429& 0.110&  0.086&  0.095&  -0.939& -0.875&
    \\&1&   -0.049& -0.039& -0.042& 0.376&  0.446&
    \\&& 1& 0.769&  0.847&  0.030&  -0.042&
    \\&&&   1&  0.583&  0.012&  -0.214&
    \\&&&&  1&  0.066&  0.004&
    \\&&&&& 1&  0.930&
    \\&&&&&&    1
    \end{matrix}
    %
    \begin{matrix}
    1&  1   -0.349& -0.393& -0.290& -0.372& -0.619& -0.638&
    \\&1&   0.142&  0.105&  0.135&  0.464&  0.668&
    \\&& 1& 0.725&  0.943&  0.396&  0.283&
    \\&&& 1& 0.648& 0.285&  0.234&
    \\&&&& 1&   0.394&  0.291&
    \\&&&&&  1& 0.907&
    \\&&&&&&    1
    \end{matrix}
    %
    \end{equation*}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! (i) please extend your code fragment to complete small document (minimal working example: mwe) , (ii) it seems that your matrices are to big to be placed two of them in one line (iii) of topic: are your matrices hasn't parenthesis/brackets?

Comment: hi and thank you for the reply. No they don't need brakets

Comment: but we still need complete document. we need to know your page layout. as matrices are now, only one can be placed in one row. . without delimiters is not possible to recognize, that they present matrices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your matrices are a bit bulky. I do not know how you want to deal with that. Other than that, you can achieve this e.g. by nesting `tabular`s.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{cc}
 \begin{tabular}{c}
  name 1\\
  $\begin{matrix}
    1&  -0.325& -0.267& -0.186& -0.249& -0.595& -0.555&\\
    &1& 0.0903& 0.063&  0.084&  0.684&  0.781&\\
    && 1&   0.68&   0.925&  0.295&  0.366&\\
    &&& 1&  0.541&  0.192&  0.213&\\
    &&&&    1&  0.296&  0.361&\\
    &&&&&   1&  0.948&\\
        &&&&&&  1
  \end{matrix}$
 \end{tabular}
 &
 \begin{tabular}{c}
  name 2\\
  $\begin{matrix}
    1& -0.264&  -0.153& -0.098& -0.140& -0.496& -0.449
    \\ &1&  0.042&  0.027&  0.039&  0.739&  0.798&
    \\&& 1& 0.627&  0.910&  0.205&  0.336&
    \\&&& 1&    0.450& 0.114&   0.192&
    \\&&&& 1&   0.211&  0.327&
    \\&&&&& 1&  0.949& 
    \\  &&&&&&  1
    \end{matrix}$
 \end{tabular}
 \\
 \begin{tabular}{c}
  name 3\\
  $\begin{matrix}
    1&  -0.429& 0.110&  0.086&  0.095&  -0.939& -0.875&
    \\&1&   -0.049& -0.039& -0.042& 0.376&  0.446&
    \\&& 1& 0.769&  0.847&  0.030&  -0.042&
    \\&&&   1&  0.583&  0.012&  -0.214&
    \\&&&&  1&  0.066&  0.004&
    \\&&&&& 1&  0.930&
    \\&&&&&&    1
    \end{matrix}$
 \end{tabular}
 &
 \begin{tabular}{c}
  name 4\\
  $\begin{matrix}
    1&  1   -0.349& -0.393& -0.290& -0.372& -0.619& -0.638&
    \\&1&   0.142&  0.105&  0.135&  0.464&  0.668&
    \\&& 1& 0.725&  0.943&  0.396&  0.283&
    \\&&& 1& 0.648& 0.285&  0.234&
    \\&&&& 1&   0.394&  0.291&
    \\&&&&&  1& 0.907&
    \\&&&&&&    1
  \end{matrix}$
 \end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much @marmot. They seem strange, but they have to be written like this :) anyway.. really thanks.. the only thing that i can't change is the margin, because i'm using a document from elsevier (elsarticle). How can i adjust the width to fix the matrices in the rigth way?

Comment: @Elisam If the matrices are wider than the page, they are wider than the page, i.e. they do not fit. You could shrink them e.g. by using `adjustbox` (I personally don't like this) or use some `sideways` environment to show them in the landscape mode, or scale all entries by 10 such that you effectively lose one digit (or just drop the `0` in `0.325`, say, i.e. type it as `.325` and similarly for the other fractional numbers).

Comment: i'm sorry, i'm really new in latex and i didn't understand what you asked to me. i don't know why you have deleted the answer. Anyway, is this what you asked me? \documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{caption,booktabs}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Pa}{Pa}
\usepackage{float}
\captionsetup{
 justification = centering
}

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}

Answer (score 0):

- it is pity, that you are not willing to help us (as i ask you twice in my comments) ... we haven't any clue about your document
- with use of `array`, some trick for aligning numbers in matrices at decimal point and using `\footnotesize` for the font size, than you can obtain:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][*\c@MaxMatrixCols c]%
{%
  \hskip -0.2\arraycolsep
  \setlength\arraycolsep{1pt}
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \array{#1}
}
\makeatother
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\footnotesize
\begin{align*}\setlength\arraycolsep{2pt}%
\begin{matrix}[*{7}{S}]
1   &-0.325 &-0.267 &-0.186 &-0.249 &-0.595 &-0.555     \\
    & 1     & 0.0903& 0.063 & 0.084 & 0.684 & 0.781     \\
    &       & 1     & 0.68  & 0.925 & 0.295 & 0.366     \\
    &       &       & 1     & 0.541 & 0.192 & 0.213     \\
    &       &       &       & 1     & 0.296 & 0.361     \\
    &       &       &       &       & 1     & 0.948     \\
    &       &       &       &       &       & 1
\end{matrix}        
%
&   \begin{matrix}[*{7}{S}]
1   &-0.264 &-0.153 &-0.098 &-0.140 &-0.496 &-0.449     \\ 
    & 1     & 0.042 & 0.027 & 0.039 & 0.739 & 0.798     \\
    &       & 1     & 0.627 & 0.910 & 0.205 & 0.336     \\
    &       &       & 1     & 0.450 & 0.114 & 0.192     \\
    &       &       &       & 1     & 0.211 & 0.327     \\
    &       &       &       &       & 1     & 0.949     \\
    &       &       &       &       &       & 1
\end{matrix}        \\
%
\begin{matrix}[*{7}{S}]
1   &-0.429 & 0.110 & 0.086 & 0.095 &-0.939 &-0.875     \\
    & 1     &-0.049 &-0.039 &-0.042 & 0.376 & 0.446     \\
    &       & 1     & 0.769 & 0.847 & 0.030 &-0.042     \\
    &       &       & 1     & 0.583 & 0.012 &-0.214     \\
    &       &       &       & 1     & 0.066 & 0.004     \\
    &       &       &       &       & 1     & 0.930     \\
    &       &       &       &       &       & 1
\end{matrix}        
%
&   \begin{matrix}[*{8}{S}]
1   & 1     &-0.349 &-0.393 &-0.290 &-0.372 &-0.619 &-0.638 \\
    & 1     & 0.142 & 0.105 & 0.135 & 0.464 & 0.668 &       \\
    &       & 1     & 0.725 & 0.943 & 0.396 & 0.283 &       \\
    &       &       & 1     & 0.648 & 0.285 & 0.234 &       \\
    &       &       & 1     & 0.394 & 0.291 &       &       \\
    &       &       &       &       & 1     & 0.907 &       \\
    &       &       &       &       &       &       & 1
\end{matrix}
    \end{align*}
```